# Create a group id when grouping by several variables

Tags: group-by, sas, grouping

I would like to create an id variable to identify the unique groups according to several variables.

For example, I have the data cars from `sashelp.cars`, and I would like to identify unique groups of `Make` - `DriveTrain` and `Cylinder` with the id variable `grp_id`. So the same `Make` and same `DriveTrain` with a different number of `Cylinder` would be considered as a new group (and hence, a new value in the id variable `grp_id`).

I tried the following, but this would reset the id variable to 1 when there is a new case, nor really considering every unique combination of `Make + DriveTrain + Cylinder` as a different group id.

```
data cars; set sashelp.cars; run;

proc sort data=cars; by Make DriveTrain Cylinders; run;
data cars; set cars; 
grp_id + 1;
by Make DriveTrain Cylinders
if first.Make or first.DriverTrain or first.Cylinders then grp_id = 1; 
run;
```

Any idea on how to create this `grp_id` variable using several variables as the criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your own code, you only have to make a small change

```
data cars; 
   set sashelp.cars; 
run;

proc sort data=cars; 
   by Make DriveTrain Cylinders; 
run;

data cars;
   set cars;
   by Make DriveTrain Cylinders;
   if first.Make or first.DriveTrain or first.Cylinders then grp_id + 1; 
run;
```

Comment: You only need first.cylinders not the remaining firsts, they overlap.

Answer (score 4):

You want each combination to have a unique group id.  Don't reset the group id.  If you were also assigning a seq number within the group, you would reset the sequence variable.

When to reset.  For combinations, increment the group id when the last listed by variable is tagged as having state `first.`

Example:

```
proc sort data=sashelp.cars out=cars; 
  by Make DriveTrain Cylinders;
run;

data cars;
  set cars;
  by Make DriveTrain Cylinders;

  if first.Cylinders then grp_id + 1;

  * this answer gives you bonus information ! ;
  if first.Cylinders 
    then seq_in_group = 1; 
    else seq_in_group + 1;
run;
```

Note: Conceptually `BY` defines a hierarchy of n variables.  When a variable in the hierarchy changes value, during a serial pass through the data, its state is set **first.*var<sub>m</sub>*=1**.  Additionally all the subordinate levels **first.** automatic variables will have the same state.  In other words, this assertion is true: **first.*var<sub>m+1</sub>*=1** ... **first.*var<sub>n</sub>*=1**.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, here is a hashing approach that does not require sorting.

```
data cars;
   if _N_ = 1 then do;
      declare hash h ();
      h.definekey ('Make', 'DriveTrain', 'Cylinders');
      h.definedata ('grp_id');
      h.definedone();
   end;

   set sashelp.cars;

   if h.find () ne 0 then grp_id + 1;
   h.replace();
run;
```